# Setting selectedIndex doesn't change jQuery Mobile dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile  control, but when do  the following:

```
$('#mySelector')[0].selectedIndex = 3
```

The underlying selector updates (I can check the selectedIndex value and it is correct) but the jQuery mobile "pretty" version that is visible does not. I can't find where in the docs to set the value programmatically. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `$('#mySelector')[0].selectedIndex = 3;` followed by `$("#mySelector").selectmenu("refresh");`.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, besides other shenanigans like the fact that apparently the site was only using jQuery mobile for certain users. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.